# Has anyone installed a Tomcat client on OSX

Tags: apache, macos, tomcat

I work in a design shop the does most of our back end work on apache servers running php.  We have a job where we need to set up a very basic project using JSP to generate some html templates for a client.

I work primarily on OSX, what's the best way to get a local apache tomcat server running on my local machine?    I'm looking for a solution that would work similar to MAMP.

I found the jakarta (http://developer.apple.com/internet/java/tomcat1.html) project but it seems that no one has posted about it since 2001.

Does anyone know a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

There are several articles on how to make this happen.  It's pretty straightforward.  Here are a couple:

http://www.malisphoto.com/tips/tomcatonosx.html

http://neilang.com/entries/how-to-install-tomcat-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 2):

The page you are mentioning is not really a project but instructions on how to install/run Tomcat on OS X. The instructions are base on Tomcat 4 which is a bit old now but you can apply them to a newer version of Tomcat. So:

1. Go to http://tomcat.apache.org/ and download Tomcat 6.x
2. Unzip it somewhere on your machine (you can follow the instructions of the link you provided)
3. Go to the bin directory and run startup.sh
4. Open http://localhost:8080/

PS: You'll need javac (i.e. a JDK, not just a JRE) on your machine to compile JSPs.

Answer (score 0):

Download Tomcat, unpack and place it anywhere you want. Get Eclipse (the j2ee edition), create an dynamic web project, point it at the directory you unpacked Tomcat, and you got yourself a nice Tomcat dev env.